# TimeZone in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, timezone

How to populate the timezone in a drop down box?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Winforms example:

```
myComboBox.DisplayMember = "DisplayName";
myComboBox.DataSource = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones();
```